# Textbox issue in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

In my app,I just have a page with four text boxes, so when i click a text box **soft keyboard** appears, now when i want to move to next textbox then i have to tap outside the textbox to make the keyboard disappear and then click on another text box. I don't think it is user friendly, so i have two options,
1)To change the functionality of return button(to make it work as tab).
2)To reduce the frame size and so scrolling will be enabled.

How can I do the foretold two options in windows phone 7??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the first option 
Make return key of the input panel work like tab key.

make key down event of 1st textbox like this

```
private void txt1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
            {
               txt2.Focus();
            }
        }
```

similarly make this event for txt2 and txt3 and give focus accordingly and on on txt4 keydown event focus the main grid.

and about the 2nd way. Its a big problem in wp according to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @Amu. How can you programmatically dismiss the soft keyboard?

Comment: that's easy .. just give the focus to main grid(Layout Root or Content Panel) or write this.focus() instead.

Answer (score 1):

For moving to next textbox @Amu 's answer will work perfect, and to dismiss the keyboard,

```
if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
  {
    this.Focus();
  }
```

That will take the focus away from your text box and will bring it to your screen.
And So keyboard will disappear!